# The client certificate clientcert.pem is not yet active

Tags: linux, certificate, ssl

I am trying to connect hypervisor from the client. I am following the document [installation document](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TLSSetup)

But When I run the command to test the connection

`virsh -c qemu+tls://host1/system hostname`

I got the error

```
error: The client certificate /etc/pki/libvirt/clientcert.pem is not yet active
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

How to activate the certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your clock in your kvm-server. This message means that your certificate is not yet active (due to the time stamp in the certificate is in the future considering the clock of your server) -> so you have either a bad clock setting on the pc where you created the certificate (and thus in the certificate) or a bad clock setting on the kvm-server. If you set your clock the connection will work.